# DetectNewerInstalledVersion Problem

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation

I'm using vs 2010, and i generate a setup file, i do have RemovePreviousVersion true and DetectNewerInstalledVersion true, at the start i had problem to remove previous version but with a hack in the MSI file it is working, not if I try to install a setup file where I have a higher one already installed on my machine, it won't be detected and will be installed separately. I'm not sure why it is not working, is it because the older version setup file was created by VS2008 ?? and didnt have the option of detectingNewerinstalledVersion true. 
who will check for the newer version the older setup version or the newer version will prevent it. 
thank you for you help in advance 
Jp

Answer (score 1):

In order for two setup projects to be considered the same application they should have different product codes, identical upgrade codes, and different version numbers.

It's hard to tell from your question if this affects you, but there is a serious issue in the way Visual Studio 2010 setup projects handle "upgrade" installations. If an assembly in the older setup has the same AssemblyFileVersionAttribute as the one in the newer setup, the installer assumes the file has not changed and will not replace it with the newer file.

One possible workaround for this problem is to include the `[ProductVersion]` in your installation directory.

Comment: In my case I just have a single VS2010 setup project and when I make updates to the source code I need the MSI to install over the old version, not install side by side.  That means I should keep ProductCode and UpgradeCode the same and increment version number?  As long as the ProductCode is the same for the new .MSI version, then the issue in VS2010 you mention about versioning the assemblies shouldnt' come into play, right?

Comment: Actually never mind I figured it out.  And great tip on adding \[ProductVersion] to the install location since that saves me a bunch of time from having to increment the assembly versions on all my individual projects of the solution